# Shutdown wall message not displaying

Tags: shutdown

I'm issuing a shutdown like this

```
shutdown -r +180 'some message'
```

The wall message is not being displayed

Comment: You've not provided any OS or release details; are users logged in to text terminals to see the message?

Comment: Plus, with 180 minutes that is way too long to see the message.  The default for the messages to show up is 15 minutes.

Comment: My mistake. I thought +180 was seconds
```Linux ip-172-31-16-236 5.11.0-1022-aw
s #23~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 15 1
4:03:19 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The question had been answered

Answer (score 4):

You won't see the wall message on your current logged in user on the physical system.  However, anyone that is logged in via ssh will see the wall messages.  Also, being logged in from SSH yourself you would not see the `shutdown` message as you would have to send it via `sudo` which will disrupt your ability to see the wall message but others logged in via ssh would still see it on the same system.

*Also, the wall messages from shutdown have a 15 minute time limit on them. Anything over 15 minutes will not show up on the wall.  It could be a bug but I am not 100% sure as it could be by design.  Anyway, I did test with 16 minutes and at 15 minutes left, no message.*

Here is an example in screenshots.  The one on the left was `ssh localhost` and the one on the right is just a normal terminal that is opened.  If you notice the one on the right is not receiving any of the messages.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: The output of the wall command itself will be displayed but not from shutdown.

Comment: @DennisGray Correct, you won't see it for yourself, even if you are logged in from an SSH session as you would have to run the shutdown command with sudo which will disrupt the message.

Comment: I logged in from another server with ssh and I do see the shutdown wall message

Comment: @DennisGray You will not see it for yourself when you are issuing the command because you have use sudo which is not your account.  If you are logged in from another server and not issuing the command from there you will see the message appear.